# Turning On Push Notifications For Parse After Disallowing It

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that uses Parse.com for Push Notifications.  My question is this...how do you handle it if a user initially doesn't allow push notifications on iOS, but then later on turns it on from Settings on their iPhone/iPad?  Does Parse detect this automatically and update their `PFInstallation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse won't automatically detect it, you will need to check at app launch and ask for permission if you have not done so in the past. Then carry on with the general push notification unpleasantries.

Comment: How do you have an app check if push notifications have been turned on via Settings since last launch?

Answer (score 1):

What? Why would Parse need to know this? And what column are you seeing in the backend that updates this? This is a user setting. All push notifications will be sent to your target channels regardless of that setting. However if they have it set to not receive it on their particular device then they just simply won't receive it. If they turn it back on at any point then theyll receive it.

It's just a light switch. You can turn it off or turn it on. Either way the circuitry still works.

Comment: If someone disallows it, the device token doesn't appear on their PFInstallation, so I'm just wondering how they get it if they later turn it on.

Comment: @user717452 thats a valid concern. However, luckily for you, you place the register for the notification types in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method which naturally gets called every time you launch the app. So anytime the user changes their preferences the next they launch the app it will register a device token. Parse doesn't update this information, you update Parse autonomously with code that's already implemented for you (`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`)